# Codeigniter 3 - Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hey guys i am wondering why i always get **Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php**

I'm trying to do is I have a controller and I want to inherit the other controller but when i call the method of the inherit controller it returns **Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php**

E.G

Controller A

```
class controller_a extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model("model");
    }

    public function methodA () {
       //the pagination codes
    }
}
```

Controller B

```
include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/controller_a.php");

class controller_b extends controller_a {
    public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->library("session");
    }

    public function methodB() {
        $a = new controller_a();
        $this->load->view("head");
        $this->load->view("navbar");
        $a->methodA();
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }
}
```

I don't why it keeps returning the error. Can anyone help me in this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please autoload the session library in `autoload.php` under `application/config` folder.

`$autoload['library'] = array('session');`

OR

Load the library inside your parent controller's constructor like in the below code.

```
class controller_a extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model("model");
         $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function methodA () {
       //the pagination codes
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering me :) but i tried to load the session but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you attempt to create `Controller_a` in `methodB()`.

Because `Controller_b` extends `Controller_a` all public and protected members of `Controller_a` are available to `Controller_b`. You get the error when you try to instantiate `Controller_a` with the line

```
$a = new controller_a();
```

This is where the error occurs. You do not need to instantiate `controller_a` that was done because it is the parent class.

`methodB()` should look like this

```
public function methodB()
{
    $this->load->view("head");
    $this->load->view("navbar");
    $this->methodA();
    $this->load->view("footer");
}
```

Not related to your problem but could cause you pain eventually are your file names and class definitions. In CI the file name and class name must be the same and must have an upper case first letter. Note the UC First usage in the following.

File *Controller_a.php* should define the class

```
class Controller_a extends CI_Controller
```

And file *Controller_b.php* should define the class

```
include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/Controller_a.php");

class Controller_b extends Controller_a
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I'll bookmark this as my reference :). I'll try your answer later. I'll rewrite what i did.

Answer (score 0):

You **must not** load session in config / autoload . you have follow my steps to solve it

step 1 : Download HMVC structure from https://github.com/alzen8work/CodeIgniter-HMVC

step 2 : remove session from application/config/autoload.php in  **$autoload['libraries'] = array()**

step 3: open application/libraries folder and open REST_Controller.php and change the line from **abstract class REST_Controller extends CI_Controller** to **abstract class REST_Controller extends MY_Controller**

step 4: open application/language/english folder and create one file name is like **rest_controller_lang**   and paste below code in it

```
     <?php
 /*
 * English language
 */
 $lang['text_rest_invalid_api_key'] = 'Invalid API key %s'; // %s is the REST API key
 $lang['text_rest_invalid_credentials'] = 'Invalid credentials';
 $lang['text_rest_ip_denied'] = 'IP denied';
 $lang['text_rest_ip_unauthorized'] = 'IP unauthorized';
 $lang['text_rest_unauthorized'] = 'Unauthorized';
 $lang['text_rest_ajax_only'] = 'Only AJAX requests are allowed';
 $lang['text_rest_api_key_unauthorized'] = 'This API key does not have access to the requested controller';
 $lang['text_rest_api_key_permissions'] = 'This API key does not have enough
```

permissions';
$lang['text_rest_api_key_time_limit'] = 'This API key has reached the time limit for this method';
$lang['text_rest_ip_address_time_limit'] = 'This IP Address has reached the time limit for this method';
$lang['text_rest_unknown_method'] = 'Unknown method';
$lang['text_rest_unsupported'] = 'Unsupported protocol';
?>

**Enjoy**